# Adding a value to geopandas empty geodataframe n times

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add a fixed value n times to an empty (geo)dataframe, I thought the below was the way to do it, but I can't seem to get it to work, where am I going wrong?

```
features = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
n=100
value = 'a'
gdf['new_column-name'] = value * n
```

Comment: Can't you handle it with this? `gdf['new_column-name'] = [value] * n`

Comment: This does the trick, if you add this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this format:

```
gdf = pd.DataFrame(value, index=range(n),columns=['new_col_name'])
```

your way of creating dataframe:

```
gdf = pd.DataFrame()
gdf['new_column-name'] = [value] * n
gdf
```

Comment: This gives: `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`

Comment: Any reason why this rather than `gdf['new_column-name'] = [value] * n` ? pros/cons?

Comment: You cannot create a dataframe directly using the values. in my answer 1. using direct pandas constructor 2. create a dataframe then assign values

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way. Thanks for giving me a chance to answer.

```
gdf['new_column-name'] = [value] * n
```

Comment: I'm trying to decide which answer to accept, why is this better than `gdf = pd.DataFrame(value, index=range(n),columns=['new_col_name'])` ?

Comment: This is because it has the least amount of code.

Comment: I also understand that you want to add 100 new rows to the gdf data frame, so